# Prove the convergence of integrals

Tags: measure-theory

I'm only allowed to use the following definition of integral to prove the result stated below:
$$
\int f d\mu=\sup \{ \int s d\mu: \ 0 \leq s \leq f, \ s \ \text{a simple function} \}
$$
Now prove that:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f \wedge n \longrightarrow \int f 
$$

My attempt: I could prove easily that $f \wedge n \leq f \implies \int f\wedge n  \leq \int f$. How do I proceed for the other direction ?

Comment: **Hint**: Given any $s$ simple function, there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n>k$ , $s \wedge n = s$.  So,  given any $s$ simple function such that $0 \leq s \leq f$, there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n>k$ , $$ \int s d\mu = \int (s \wedge n) d\mu \leq \int f \wedge n $$

Comment: @Ramiro: Thanks a lot. That does the trick :)